# junit - how to mock field in real class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a tricky situation. I am using MVP architecture for android but thats not important. I have a class called DoStandardLoginUsecase that basically just connects to a server with login info and gets a access token. i am trying to test it. But the problem is the context that i am passing in to it so i can initialize dagger.

```
    public class DoStandardLoginUsecase extends BaseUseCase {

    @Inject
    UserDataRepository mUserDataRepo;

    private StandardLoginInfo loginInfo;


    public DoStandardLoginUsecase(Context context) {
/* SEE HERE I AM USING A APPLICATION CONTEXT THAT I PASS TO DAGGER
*/
        ((MyApplication)context).getPresenterComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Login> buildUseCaseObservable() {
        return mUserDataRepo.doStandardLogin(loginInfo);
    }

    public void setLoginInfo(StandardLoginInfo loginInfo) {
        this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
    }
}
```

and here is the test i have so far:

```
 public class DoStandardLoginUsecaseTest {

    DoStandardLoginUsecase standardLoginUsecase;
        StandardLoginInfo fakeLoginInfo;
    TestObserver<Login> subscriber;

MockContext context;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
//now when i create the object since its a mock context it will fail when it tries to call real things as these are stubs.  So how do i test this object. how do i create an instance of this object ?  I am willing to use [daggerMock][1] if that helps also. 
standardLoginUsecase = New DoStandardLoginUsecase(context); 
            fakeLoginInfo = new StandardLoginInfo("fred@hotmail.com","Asdfgh4534");
            subscriber = TestObserver.create();
        }


       @Test
        public void buildUseCaseObservable(){

standardLoginUsecase.seLoginInfo(fakeLoginInfo);
    standardLoginUsecase.buildUseCaseObservable().subscribe(subscriber);

           subscriber.assertNoErrors();
           subscriber.assertSubscribed();
           subscriber.assertComplete();
       }
    }
```

Comment: You can create mocks using `Mockito.mock`

Comment: Can you show me. Because i tried @mock Context c; already. But the dagger call needs real context.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to have a `@Rule` in order to make `@Mock` work. But you can also simply create mocks with the function `Mockito.mock`. I have done this approach in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the test like this:

```
 public class DoStandardLoginUsecaseTest {

      private DoStandardLoginUsecase target;
      private MyApplication contextMock;

      @Before
      public void beforeEach() {
          contextMock = Mockito.mock(MyApplication.class);
          // Note that you need to mock the getPresenterComponent
          // but I don't know what it returns.
          target = new DoStandardLoginUsecase(contextMock);
      }

      @Test
      public void buildUseCaseObservable() {
           UserDataRepository userDataMock = Mockito.mock(UserDataRepository.class);
           StandardLoginInfo loginInfoMock = Mockito.mock(StandardLoginInfo.class);
           target.mUserDataRepo = userDataMock;
           target.setLoginInfo(loginInfoMock);

           Observable<Login> expected = // create your expected test data however you like...
           Mockito.when(userDataMock.doStandardLogin(loginInfoMock)).thenReturn(expected);
           Observable<Login> actual = target.buildUseCaseObservable();

           Assert.areSame(actual, expected);
      }

 }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. but your saying that when userDataMock is called return the "expcted". then your actually calling the real thing called . target.buildUseCaseObservable() which is only going to give you back the "expected" value. It seems it not a real test. the actual will ALWAYs be the expected. What do you think ?

Comment: Change your implementation and see if the expected value is still returned